# AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'get_type'

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib

Ok, I'm trying to use opener with beautiful soup to extract some info from a page, and I think that's where the problem is arising.  I need to use opener because I need to route it through Tor, as I think they have blocked multiple requests.

(If this is all unformatted I'll edit straight away, as usually something weird happens.)

Here's the code:

```
def getsite():
    proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    url = opener.open('https://www.website.com')
    try:
        page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    except Exception as Err:
        errorlist.append('Unexpected Error ' + str(Err))
        time.sleep(60)
        page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    values = page.findAll("strong")
    high = values[2]
    low = values[1]
    last = values[0]
    vol = values[3]

    high = str(high)
    low = str(low)
    last = str(last)
    vol = str(vol)
    high = high[8:-13]
    low = low[8:-13]
    last = last[8:-13]
    vol = vol[8:-24]


    print high, low, last, vol

while True:
    getsite()
    time.sleep(3200)
```

And it throws up this error.

```
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 392, in open
protocol = req.get_type() AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'get_type'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you you're using the opener object as though it was a URL:

```
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

Where `url` is the opened opener... instead, do:

```
page = BeautifulSoup(url.read())
```

Comment: Huh, not quite sure I understand that.  It works, but that isn't using opener anymore is it?

Could you explain it a bit more by any chance?

EDIT:  Nevermind, got confused.  Thanks mate.